# Using scriptlet or EL inside an attribute of a tag (Grails UI Plugin)

Tags: grails, tags, el, gsp, scriptlet

I want to trigger the same dialog on different ids in my gsp. 
So here is the code:

```
 <div class="yui3-widget-bd">
   <g:each in="deployments" status="index" var="workflow">
      <% def id = "reloadFile"+index %>
         <gui:dialog title="Reload File" form="true" modal="true"
                     controller="admin" action="reloadFile"
                     triggers="[show:[id:'${id}', on:'click']]">
         <p>To reload the file, please...</p><br />
         <input type="file" id="deploymentFile" name="deploymentFile" />
         </gui:dialog>
   </g:each>
</div>
```

The problem is that the scriptlet code :

```
triggers="[show:[id:'<%=id %>', on:'click']]"
```

is not getting evaluated. 
The Javascript part that listens for events in the source of the generated html looks like this:

```
 YAHOO.util.Event.addListener("${id}", "click", GRAILSUI.gui_e0100d149e0a7b531017e0decaee9fce.show, GRAILSUI.gui_e0100d149e0a7b531017e0decaee9fce, true);
```

So how can i manage that the source looks like this ? :

```
YAHOO.util.Event.addListener("reloadFile1", "click", GRAILSUI.gui_e0100d149e0a7b531017e0decaee9fce.show, GRAILSUI.gui_e0100d149e0a7b531017e0decaee9fce, true);
```

Thank you.

Comment: What about removing the single quotes around ${id}? (triggers="[show:[id:${id}, on:'click']]")

Comment: Thanks for your answer Todd, but that's not working. I get a GrailsTagException. Any further ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Same as jsps:

- If you want to execute some code

  <% def something = true %>
- If you want to use the return of the execution

  <%= something ? "This is a truth statement" : "This is false" %>

Beware that this is probably code smell and the code should be in a domain, controller or taglib 99.9% of cases.

[Here's the reference documentation for more info.](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/guide/theWebLayer.html#GSPBasics)